# python pexpect module: How to save output into a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pexpect

When using the python3 pexpect module, how do you save everything that was printed to stdout into a list or variable that I can look at afterwards?

Here's a really basic example where we are just waiting for "Prompt" and then sending "foo".   Afterwards I want to check what was in STDOUT and print data based on that.   It seems that once you run `p.read()` it empties and is no longer accessible?  How can I save the entire stdout output and access it later on, even after `p.close()` is run?  In this example if the if statement is true it works but if it is false you can no longer read what was in stdout with `p.read()`.

```
import pexpect

p = pexpect.spawn(cmd)
p.expect("Prompt")
p.sendline("foo")


if "Command was successful" in p.read():
  print ("successful")
else:
  print (p.read())

p.expect(pexpect.EOF)
p.close()
```

Comment: You can turn on transcript logging by assigning to `p.logfile`.  Make it an `io.BytesIO` object if you want to keep it in memory.

Comment: Can you please show me how to do that?   I couldn't get it working with p.logfile but after googling what you wrote I found a similar way to save the output into a list by importing the BytesIO module and then setting "byte_stream = BytesIO(p.read())" followed by "log = byte_stream.read()".   I then read the log object instead with "log.decode()".  I can't seem to post the full code here in this comment or else I'd paste the full output.

Comment: Well, if ALL you want is whatever the app sent back, all you need is `text = p.read()`.  Now you have a string, and you can do whatever you want with it.  I thought you wanted a transcript of both sides of the conversation.

Comment: That only works if there is only a single prompt that pexpect has to respond to.  The problem is that my real script has to answer several prompts and it seems that once you access p.read() in any way you can no longer continue the script as the next prompt hangs since the object is now empty.  After each p.expect and p.sendline I want to capture the output into a variable, check the output, and then do the same thing again after each pexpect and sendline .  I did find a solution using something similar that you suggested using BytesIO but I'm curious if it could be done with just pexpect

Answer (score 1):

This is simple example, without logging and parallel execution like "threads\multiprocessing\concurent"
A simplest way to save prints from your host\switch or smth, it's using .before.decode('utf-8')

Here is example of function that receive hostIP\name, log, pw, and list of commands:

```py
def connectToHost(Ip, login, password, cmdPool):
    output=''
    Port = "22"
    HostKeyCheck = " -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "
    ssh = pexpect.spawn("ssh -p "+Port+HostKeyCheck+login+"@"+ Ip, timeout=30)
    ssh.expect(r'sword:')
    ssh.sendline(password)
    print('Connected to '+ Ip)
    ssh.expect('$')
    output+=ssh.before.decode('utf-8')
    for cmdLine in cmdPool:
        ssh.sendline(cmdLine)
        ssh.expect('$')
        output+=ssh.before.decode('utf-8')
    ssh.close()
    return output
```

usage:

```py
login = 'user'
password = '192929'
cmdPool = [
'ls -al',
'pwd',
'du -hs',
]
hosts = ['1.1.1.1', '12.2.2.2']
results = []
for ip in hosts:
    results.append(connectToHost(ip, login, password, cmdPool))
print(results)
```

Next step you can add something like logging instead of print().
Then you can use parallel if u need.

P.s Pay attention if u need log it into file pexpect has native arg logfile. This is example from pexpect docs:

```py
child = pexpect.spawn('some_command')
fout = open('mylog.txt','wb')
child.logfile = fout
```

Comment: If you use the simple example I provided at the top if you use "before" or "after" it will only print part of the prompt.   I don't need either, I need to capture the output it produces while still allowing me to run "p.read())" in the future.  Using "p.read()" gives me the output I need but once you acccess it once it seems to empty and is no longer available to query it again.

Comment: Sry i don't understand what you does mean. Could you update it with examples of expected result?
Like a:
I send it: ```ls -al```
I receive: ``` ABC``
But i expect to receive answer : ``` CDE ```
 So i can try ti help you then.